# How to extract beginning part of 3D model files using Blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, command-line

The business purpose is that I allow registered user upload different 3D model files. When other users review the file, he or she does not need to download the whole file (size about several Gbs), he or she could make preview the 3D model files with the biginning a couple of 3D frames. In this way, he or she could know about the 3D file roughtly, then decide to download or not.

Challenge is 3D model formats are hundreds, we already know that the users have different 3D model tools (Aveva for example) to make different 3d format files. Lets make it easier at first, that is to say it could take this preview a couple of minutes or not that real time (seconds for example).

The question with above scenario could we use blender in command line utility to generate all kinds of 3d model files's prview videos or pictures?

====================

## second edition

I found following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483003/how-to-rotate-a-camera-around-obj-wavefront-file-contents) could help me to make preview of a 3D model. The link has following code snippets.

```
import bpy
scn = bpy.context.scene

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath='E:\\sjj\\Blender\demoFile\Demo_274\Ring_27.blend')
target = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
scn.objects.active = target
# centring the origin gives a better bounding box and rotation point
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')

cam_x_pos = max([v[0] for v in target.bound_box]) * 2.5
print('cam_x_pos: {}'.format(cam_x_pos))     //it prints cam_x_pos is 0.0  
cam_y_pos = max([v[1] for v in target.bound_box]) * 2.5
print('cam_y_pos is: ',cam_y_pos)            //it prints cam_y_pos is 0.0    
cam_z_pos = max([v[2] for v in target.bound_box]) * 2.5
print('cam_z_pos is: ',cam_z_pos)            //it prints cam_z_pos is: 0.0

rot_centre = bpy.data.objects.new('rot_centre', None)
scn.objects.link(rot_centre)
rot_centre.location = target.location

camera = bpy.data.objects.new('camera', bpy.data.cameras.new('camera'))
scn.objects.link(camera)
camera.location = (cam_x_pos, cam_y_pos, cam_z_pos)
camera.parent = rot_centre
m = camera.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
m.target = target
m.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
m.up_axis = 'UP_Y'

rot_centre.rotation_euler.z = 0.0
rot_centre.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', index=2, frame=1)
rot_centre.rotation_euler.z = math.radians(360.0)
rot_centre.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', index=2, frame=101)
# set linear interpolation for constant rotation speed
for c in rot_centre.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    for k in c.keyframe_points:
        k.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
scn.frame_end = 100
```

I modified a little bit of original codes,

```
rot_centre.rotation_euler.z = radians(360.0) =>
rot_centre.rotation_euler.z = math.radians(360.0)
```

Why `cam_x_pos, cam_y_pos,cam_z_pos` are printed as `0.0`.? And how to let camera take shots/snapshots so that I could get some pictures (jpeg,png,gif)

The file Ring_27.blend looks like:
[image]

Comment: yes and no. If you are asking how to create a collection of preview images/animations from a library of 3D objects then; the object has to be in a format that Blender can read/import, there is a camera setup or the object is in a known location that a camera can be pointed at, lighting is provided or reliably generated. Best thing at this point is to try it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html

Comment: If the file format is one recognized by blender then you can write a python script to (1) import the obj (2) determine the bounding box and scale it down/up to some standard dimension (3) add camera at a fixed point (4) add track to constraint (5) move the camera and set the key frames at both the points of movement (6) render the video of the frames within the camera movement.

Comment: Let's suppose blender know the file format. How to follow the steps, are there detail instructions to tell the steps mentioned above, for example how to import the obj?

Comment: I found blend python api could open file and have python api to access objects. step 4, 5,6  seems difficult to me.

Comment: official blender has an addon called "turnaround camera", that could help you somehow with step 5. If you feel a single step difficult, try browsing here fore previous similar questions, there may be an answer already. If not, ask a question about a specific step, show what you tried, and someone will help you.

Comment: @BlenderDadaist please check my second edition, it makes my question towards goal, that is to take snapshot of a 3D model.

Comment: The code is setting `target = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]`. If it's a non-mesh like camera, its bbox will have co 0 (try printing `bpy.context.selected_objects[0].name`). You can maybe find the object with `bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data.vertices` attribute so that you get the mesh object. You can take a snapshot with `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = 'path_to_png'` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982836/rendering-and-saving-images-through-blender-python]